# Not clicked Button get's colored

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I have a multipage application. When I click a button on page 1, i'm navigation to page 2 - unfortunately, the button on page 2 (which is at the same position) is colored automatically as "hovered". 
Is there a simple workaround?

[image]

I'm using
jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js and
jquery-2.0.0.min.js

Thank you very much for helping!
The HTLM

```
        <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: CalendarScreen  -->
    <div data-role="page" id="calendarScreen" data-dom-cache="true">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="background-color: white">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><img class="dataMigLogo"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><img class="dataMigBlueLine"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="lb_sync" class="whiteTextNoShadow"><img src="../../res/icon/upload.png" style="height:74px;"><br>Synchronisieren</div>
            <div id="lb_info" class="whiteTextNoShadow">Letzter Sync:<br><div id="syncInfoDate"></div><div id="syncInfoTime"></div></div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="calendarContent">
        </div>
        <div id="calendarPlugin"></div>
        <!-- Neu eingefuegt Daniel -->
        <div data-role="footer" id="ui-footer-div" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div id="fiveButtons" class="center-wrapper" style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
                <div class="b"><button id="liBtn_navbar_monthlyApp" style="margin-left:20px" class="c ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-left">Übersicht</button></div>
                <div class="b"><button id="liBtn_navbar_settApp" class="c ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-gear ui-btn-icon-left">Einstellungen</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <!-- Page: SettingScreen  -->
    <div data-role="page" id="settingScreen" data-dom-cache="true">
        <!-- Header -->
        <div data-role="header" class="fixedHeader" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <div class="ui-grid-b" style="background-color: white">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><img class="dataMigLogo"></div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><img class="dataMigBlueLine"></div>
            </div>
            <label class="lb_info"></label>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div style="margin-left: 3%; width: 93%; padding-bottom: 120px; padding-top: 120px;">
                <h1>Übersicht:</h1>
                <!-- Tabelle, die 2 Spalten hat -->
                <div class="div30">SOME CONTENT</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" id="ui-footer-div" class="fixedFooter" data-tap-toggle="false">
                            <div id="fiveButtons" class="center-wrapper" style="margin-bottom:10px float:left "> 
                <div class="b"><button id="liBtn_navbar_backSettings" style="margin-left:20px" class="c ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left">Zurück</button></div>
                <div class="b"><button id="liBtn_navbar_saveSettings" class="c ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Speichern</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
//Page change to Calendar -> Setting
$('#liBtn_navbar_settApp').tap(function()   {
    setSettingValues();
    $.mobile.changePage("#settingScreen", {transition: "slide"});
    $("#collSettings").trigger("collapse");
    setHeadValue("Einstellungen. Hier können alle relevanten Einstellungen vorgenommen werden.", "white");
});
```

There are no changes in the css for the buttons!

Comment: cooode speaks more than images :) fiddle pls

Comment: are you using buttons or links styled as buttons? do the elements have different ids?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using normal buttons with different IDs

Comment: `$(".ui-btn-active").removeClass("ui-btn-active")` or just use _anchors_ instead of `button`.

Comment: complete code & and are you using ajax

Comment: Thanks. I've updated it. The code inspector says, that the button is in "hover" state. But I can't reproduce this issue on a browser - only on mobile devices it appears. I also checked, if this is a "ghost click" event, but the tap is only fired once.....

Comment: check your custom theme. it cant be reproduced without your custom theme stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to change the css of `buttonElement:visited` to the default css styles. And place the onclick css changes to `buttonElement:active`.

Not sure though, we need to see your css and your method of changing the buttons style. Do you use plain css, jquery, or javascript?